# Preconfigure column types when using DataGrip to import from CSV

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, datagrip

I'm using DataGrip 2016.3 to connect to a PostgreSQL server.

When I right click and Import From File, currently DataGrip makes assumptions about the type associated with each column
[(see image for what DataGrip defaults to in the import dialog)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtqlE.png). I'd like to specify that column A is VARCHAR(50), column B is INT, column C is DATE, and so on. I will be uploading similar files multiple times, and I'd like to avoid having to specify my types each time I import. Is there a way to save and select configurations of columns A, B, and C's types?

Comment: There is no feature like this. Please, follow the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-4917

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I've found to accomplish this is to first create the destination table.  Then Right-click on the table in the database tool window to launch the "Import Data from File..." wizard.

This is also great if you want the destination table to contain additional columns, such as an auto-incrementing id column.